# I purchased wordpress theme from themeforest but not able to import demo content?

Tags: wordpress, import, wordpress-theming, themes, demo

As I purchased WordPress theme from themeforest and installed it. But I am not able to get demo content as seen in preview section of that theme.
From import demo data menu I tried importing demo manually as only xml file showing in theme file which I downloaded(purchased) but still not getting.
Plz help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often in TF themes, there is a configuration menu to import data and plugins related to the theme, specific to each theme.
Read the documentation on the Zip File

Answer (score 0):

TF themes come with support offered by the theme's developer(s).
You might want to log a ticket with them if you don't find anything in the theme's documentation.